# Помогите с питоном пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Антон Ежикеев — страшный тролль, который любил троллить своих собеседников: отвечать их же фразами, только наоборот. Если фраза была некрасивой (звучала наоборот так же, как и при прямом прочтении), то он говорил "хочу кумса". Время шло, а привычка не пропадала, да и количество диалогов возрастало, поэтому он попросил свою подругу-программиста Катю написать его цифрового двойника, который будет общаться с людьми.

Антон любил хвастаться, поэтому попросил Катю добавить в бота ведение статистики, сколько раз за сегодня он затроллил людей (фразы были красивыми).

Так как Катя давно не писала двойников, то сделав программу, она обнаружила, что двойник ведет себя как-то странно. Помогите ей починить двойника Антона, указав строчки, в которых содержатся ошибки.
Строки с ошибками вводите по порядку без пробелов, чтобы получилось число.

Например, 13679

Входные данные

В первой строке указано N количество диалогов. 
В следующих N строках указаны диалоги собеседников Антона, которым нужно дать ответ.
Фраза состоять из строчных символов русского алфавита (кроме ё) и пробелов

```
5 
привет 
как дела 
а роза упала на лапу азора 
что ты любишь делать антон 
кот учен но не чуток
```

Выходные данные

N строк с диалогами Антона и после этого количество раз, в которых Антон затроллил собеседников.

```
тевирп 
алед как 
хочу кумса 
нотна ьталед ьшибюл ыт отч 
котуч ен он нечу ток 
4
```

Программа Кати

Python

```
n = int(input())
trolled = 0  # 1
for i in range(n):
    line = input()
    l_pos = 0
    r_pos = len(line)  # 2
    is_kums = True  # 3
    while l_pos <= r_pos and is_kums: 
        if line[l_pos] == ' ':
            l_pos += 1  # 4
            continue
        if line[r_pos] == ' ':
            r_pos += 1  # 5
            continue
        if line[l_pos] != line[r_pos]:  # 6
            is_kums = False  # 7
        l_pos -= 1  # 8
        r_pos += 1  # 9
    if is_kums:
        print('хочу кумса')
        trolled = 1  # 10
    else:
        print(line[::-1])
print(trolled)
```

Я считаю,что верные цифры - 2,4,5,8,10
Но это не верно, в чем ошибка ?

Comment: В `#10` должно быть `trolled += 1`, `#1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7` -- правильно. `#5, 8, 9` -- неправильно, т.к. для `l_pos` индексация идет с 0 и выше, `r_pos` -- наоборот (поэтому и `#5` неправильно). Для #7 я бы еще `break` добавил, т.к. смысла нет дальше перебирать

Comment: А почему 2 правильно ? Если индексация с 0,то len считает с 1

Comment: Точно, не обратил внимание, `#2` неправильно, там должно быть `r_pos = len(line) - 1`, иначе на первом же `line[r_pos]` будет выход за пределы списка. А вообще, если по простому, то весь цикл `while` с флагом `is_kums` спокойно заменяется одной строкой: `is_kums = line == line[::-1]`, т.е. проверкой равна ли строка с строкой наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

```py
n = int(input())
trolled = 0  # 1 - тут все верно
for i in range(n):
    line = input()
    l_pos = 0
    r_pos = len(line)  # 2 - len(line) - 1
    is_kums = True  # 3 - ok
    while l_pos <= r_pos and is_kums: 
        if line[l_pos] == ' ':
            l_pos += 1  # 4 - ok
            continue
        if line[r_pos] == ' ':
            r_pos += 1  # 5 - r_pos-= 1
            continue
        if line[l_pos] != line[r_pos]:  # 6
            is_kums = False  # 7 - можно и так
        l_pos -= 1  # 8 - l_pos += 1
        r_pos += 1  # 9 - r_pos -= 1
    if is_kums:
        print('хочу кумса')
        trolled = 1  # 10 - trolled += 1  
    else:
        print(line[::-1])
print(trolled)
```

а вообще всю эту проверку можно сократить дo, как и упомянул @gil9red, word == word[::-1]